# Basic query regarding React Events behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I am new to React. While following a [CS50 youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HMtarQAt3A), I followed them and created a sample todo list project using `create-react-app`. I only made changes to the `App.js` file as shown below:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos: [],
      currentTodo: ''
    };
  }

  onInputChange = e => {
    this.setState({currentTodo: e.target.value})
  }

  addTodo = () => {
    let todosCopy = this.state.todos.slice();
    todosCopy.push(this.state.currentTodo);
    this.setState({
      todos: todosCopy,
      currentTodo: ''
    })
  }

  deleteTodo = (i) => {
    let todosCopy = this.state.todos.slice();
    todosCopy.splice(i, 1);
    this.setState({
      todos: todosCopy
    })
  }


  render() {
    let todosList = this.state.todos.map((todo, i) => {
      return (
        <li key={i}>{todo}<button onClick={() =>this.deleteTodo(i)}>x</button></li>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <input value={this.state.currentTodo} onChange={this.onInputChange}/><button onClick={this.addTodo}>Add Todo</button>
        {this.state.todos.length === 0 ? <p>No todos</p> : <ul>{todosList}</ul>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My query is that for adding a todo, the `onClick` is referred to `this.addTodo` like:

```
<button onClick={this.addTodo}>Add Todo</button>
```

And it works but for deleting a todo why do we have to write it like:

```
<button onClick={() =>this.deleteTodo(i)}>x</button>
```

Why can't be write it like below similar to addTodo and pass it reference to i?

```
<button onClick={this.deleteTodo(i)}>x</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing `this.deleteTodo(i)` is *invoking* the function. What you would end up giving to `onClick` is what is returned from `this.deleteTodo(i)`, which in this case is `undefined`.

`() => this.deleteTodo(i)` is creating a new function. It might look a bit more clear at first if you write it like `function () { this.deleteTodo(i) }.bind(this)` as an exercise.

It boils down to that event handler props (`onClick`, `onChange`, ...) should be given a function reference it can call when the event occurs.

Comment: then why can't we do the same with `addTodo`? Like `<button onClick={() => this.addTodo()}>Add Todo</button>`

Comment: @AsadFerozAli You can do `() => this.addTodo()`, but you don't need to. `this.addTodo` is also a function, and it will work fine. The problem arises when you need to pass in an argument to the function. If you wanted to pass an argument to `this.addTodo`, you would have to write `() => this.addTodo(myArg)`

Comment: Thanks a ton for explaining!

Comment: @AsadFerozAli You're welcome! It's a little tricky in the beginning, but you will be comfortable with it soon.